# How to integrated keystonejs in an existing express and mongoose project?

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

i created node js application with express and mongoose and it's running fine.Now i want to use keystonejs for build an admin ui in my existing project.
Is it possible?If it possible can you share some thoughts.Thanks in advanced

Comment: Did it work for you ?, I simply can't find a simple way to do that, I see that I need to change my models structure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Wiki: [How to add keystone to an existing Express app](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/How-to-Add-Keystone-to-an-Already-Existing-Express-App)

Comment: Link is dead. SO answers shouldn't just be a link.